# Codeigniter. WHERE sql with multiple values

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have content that i want to filter by a brandname and a permission id and then show it.

my problem is:
When i send one value as $permission it works fine. But when a user has multiple permission_id's it doesnt work.

WHERE `permission_id` = 1, 2, 3;

I have a problem with my select query:

Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('content');
$this->db->where('brand_name', $brand);
$this->db->where('permission_id', $permission);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `brand_name` = $brand_name AND `permission_id` = $permission;
```

The print_r of $brand & $permission look like this:

```
Hyundai
1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I hope i gave enough information for someone to help me like this.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test a field against multiple values, your SQL should not look like :

```
WHERE permission_id = 1, 2, 3;
```

I don't know what your `permission_id` field looks like, but I guess your condition should rather be:

```
WHERE permission_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Try with `where_in`:

```
$this->db->where_in('permission_id', $permission);
```

where `$permission` is an array containing the permissions (not a comma separated string).

With `$permission` being a string, use `explode`:

```
$this->db->where_in('permission_id', explode(',', $permission));
```